# WP Schedule Event - Every Day When First Visitor Comes

Tags: actions, wp-cron

I have a daily wp schedule event.

I know that it happens when a user visits the site and if a schedule time passes.

If I started it on today 12 a.m. and if tomorrow first visitor comes tomorrow 1:20 a.m. that event happen tomorrow 1:20 a.m..

Day after day, it happens after 1.20 a.m. or after 12 a.m.?

Comment: The event is triggered as soon as the user visits the page. It doesn't delay.

Comment: The next schedule will be on 12 AM again!

Comment: @sumit Are you sure about that? One of my friend said that if today it happens in 1.20 a.m next day it will happen after 1.20 a.m, not the 12 a.m.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*wp-cron* is often called a pseudo-cron, because it doesn't run on a strict schedule. If nobody visits the site, it doesn't run. If you schedule a wp-cron event to run, say, every 12 hours, it will run *at most* every 12 hours. But, if your site has very little traffic, there could be far more than 12 hours between runs.

If you need an event to happen every 12 hours, or every day at the same time, you'll need to use something outside of WordPress. Common approaches to that include using the system task scheduler (on Linux, this is usually called "cron") or a third-party service like EasyCron.

Assuming you're on a Linux server (by far the most common hosting environment), create a small shell script that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl http://yoursite.name.com/wp-cron.php >/dev/null
```

This will run the "curl" command, to load your site's wp-cron.php page, then immediately ignore the results (by dumping the output to /dev/null). You don't care about any output the page might have, and in fact there normally isn't any output. You just want to be sure the page is loaded.

Then, add a line to your crontab ("crontab -e" will open the crontab file in your default editor, probably *vi*) that looks something like this:

```
0 0,12 * * *             /home/user/touch-site.sh
```

(Obviously, modify the file location to wherever you put your script. Also, be sure the script is executable by running "chmod 700 touch-site.sh".)

This example will visit your site daily, at noon and midnight (server time), and run the wp-cron script. For more details on how this file works, run "man crontab".

Answer (score 0):

To answer your this query

> *@sumit Are you sure about that? One of my friend said that if today it happens in 1.20 a.m next day it will happen after 1.20 a.m, not the 12 a.m.*

**How it works:**

1. You schedule an event using current time stamp i.e. 12:00 AM on Monday

   ```
   wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily', 'my_schedule_hook');
   ```
2. Someone visited the site on Monday at 1:20 AM.

WP call this piece of code

```
    if ( $schedule != false ) {
            $new_args = array($timestamp, $schedule, $hook, $v['args']);
            call_user_func_array('wp_reschedule_event', $new_args);
    }

    wp_unschedule_event( $timestamp, $hook, $v['args'] );

   /**
    * Fires scheduled events.
    *
    * @ignore
    * @since 2.1.0
    *
    * @param string $hook Name of the hook that was scheduled to be fired.
    * @param array  $args The arguments to be passed to the hook.
    */
    do_action_ref_array( $hook, $v['args'] );
```

Here it is calling `wp_reschedule_event()` function which uses the same timestamp so the next schedule will be Tuesday 12:00 AM **NOT** 1:20 AM. Then it will call schedule action hook.

3. Common mistake people do is they call `wp_schedule_event()` directly in `functions.php` so WP schedule event on every new timestamp. The correct way is check if schedule is there only then create it.

   ```
   $my_schedule_hook = wp_next_scheduled('my_schedule_hook');
   if (!$my_schedule_hook) {
       wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily', 'my_schedule_hook');
   }
   ```

Thus it will only go inside the `if` block only at first time when there will be no schedule at all.
Still you can view all the schedule by this plugin [WP Crontrol](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-crontrol/)